# How can I forward declare an array inside a namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, definition, name-lookup

I've been trying to find out how I can use namespaces properly. I want to use a namespace, but not have to define it in the header file. I am not sure how I can do this with an array inside the namespace. I either get an "already defined symbol" error, or I get told that the namespace has not been declared.

I have tried to write code like this:

```cpp
//Header.h

namespace foo {
    int array[5];
}
```

```cpp
//Source.cpp

#include "Header.h"

namespace foo {
    int array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

And it returns an error.

If I try to forward-declare the namespace, like I would any other variable, it says the namespace is undefined, so I'm not sure what the correct way to achieve this is.

```cpp
//Header.h

extern int foo::array;
```

```cpp
//Source.cpp

#include "Header.h"

namespace foo {
    
    int array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

}
```

Comment: That makes sense, is it best practice to just declare and define namespaces in header files? Or should I avoid using a namespace in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as in global namespace:

```
// .h
namespace foo {
    extern int array[5];
}
```

```
// .cpp
namespace foo {
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel like a noob

Comment: In the `.cpp` file, you can alternatively use `int foo::array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` without using another `namespace {}` block. But if you have other things being defined in the same namespace, the block makes sense to use.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
namespace foo {

    int array[5];

}
```

is a definition of the array.

On the other hand, this declaration

```
extern int foo::array;
```

is present in the global namespace instead of the namespace `foo`. That is the namespace `foo` was not yet declared and you may not use the qualified name `foo::array`.

To declare the array in the header use the storage specifier `extern`.

```
namespace foo {

    extern int array[5];

}
```

And then in the cpp file you can write for example

```
int foo::array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: Ohh, wow, that makes sense. I'm annoyed I didn't think of that. Thank you!